# $or query with multiple parameters

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to achieve the following

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE   (_currentMatch = null AND
        unregistrated = false AND
        gender = 'male' AND
        lastMatchTime < dateMale)
OR      (_currentMatch = null AND
        unregistrated = false AND
        gender = 'female' AND
        lastMatchTime < dateFemale);
```

with mongoose:

```
User.find(
    {
        $or:[{
                lastMatchTime: {$lt: dateMale},
                _currentMatch: null,
                unregistrated: false,
                gender: 'male'
            },
            {
                lastMatchTime: {$lt: dateFemale},
                _currentMatch: null,
                unregistrated: false,
                gender: 'female'
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

This query doesn't seem to match all given conditions. Am I missing a `$and`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing that the first two conditions `(_currentMatch = null AND unregistrated = false)` are duplicated in both the OR clauses, your SQL query can
be re-written as:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE   
    _currentMatch = null 
    AND unregistrated = false 
    AND gender in ('female', 'male')
```

The equivalent mongo query follows:

```
User.find({
    "_currentMatch": null,
    "unregistrated": false,
    "gender": { "$in": ["female", "male"] }
})
```

---

**-- UPDATE --**

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE   (_currentMatch = null AND
        unregistrated = false AND
        gender = 'male' AND
        lastMatchTime < dateMale)
OR      (_currentMatch = null AND
        unregistrated = false AND
        gender = 'female' AND
        lastMatchTime < dateFemale);
```

can be re-written as

```
User.find({
    "_currentMatch": null,
    "unregistrated": false,
    "$or": [
        { "gender": "female", "lastMatchTime": { "$lt": dateFemale } },
        { "gender": "male", "lastMatchTime": { "$lt": dateMale } }
    ]
})
```

Comment: The queries are simplified. There are different conditions. I'll update my question. **Updated**

Comment: So is my initial query wrong or should it also work? Your query is obviously shorter.

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to include a bunch of sample documents that we can test the queries with?

Comment: I already tried the queries on my live server, they both deliver the same results. But yours is quite shorter, so I take it :)